# iOS: Switching to Portrait ViewController from LandScape ViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, orientation

I have a VC in Portrait which presents another VC that can either be portrait or landscape. The problem is that when I return back to the original VC that presented it, it is also shown in landscape until I rotate it and then it stays in portrait. What I want is to always have the original VC to always be portrait, how can I achieve this? Here it the code that I use to set up the VC orientations after I have set the supported orientations in my PList:

In the original VC, that should always be portrait

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

In my VC that could either be portrait or landscape, I have:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Override the supportedInterfaceOrientations method and return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown.

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown;
}
```

Comment: That orientation is not supported by my application and it surely crashes. I need to support portrait and not PortraitUpsideDown.

Comment: Then choose one of the enum values from UIInterfaceOrientationMask, the one that supports your application.

Comment: Thanks but choosing one will not work. This is a fairly complex application and I have experimented way beyond your suggestion. I will keep researching this until I find the solution, hopefully more ideas also come in.